# Can I add a member to a specific card without adding them to the board as a whole?

Tags: trello

I have 2 boards - one project based with members and on that is 'private' todo lists with only me as admin / member. Can I invite a member from the other board to be able to view / interact with a specific card on my personal board without them viewing all my other cards? (At the moment I cannot see any invitees in the add member box within the card)

Comment: Not what you asked for, but [Astrid.com](https://astrid.com) is a todo list tool that does allow you to share individual tasks or entire lists with other users without revealing your private tasks.

Comment: [This question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37792/is-there-any-way-to-send-a-trello-card-to-an-outside-user/75061#75061) is not exactly what you asked, but has some solutions (for viewing only, not interacting).

Answer (score 2):

I have just recently tried to do this myself. It does not seem possible. What I did instead (not a complete workaround) was to create a new board in an organization that is visible to the organization members. They can view, vote, and comment, but nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

That would not be possible. Usually by my understanding, at this moment, Trello does not allow you to specify permissions on cards. You can only add members to a card after adding them to the board.

Comment: OK, thanks. But once added to a board you can then add members again to individual cards. I am not sure what purpose this serves ... hence my question above.

Comment: That would be similar to task delegation. Something like saying: "The task of finishing up on this card is handed over to the following people..."

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I've built another board and added the people I want to have access to those cards onto it, then created a [Butler](https://help.butlerfortrello.com/article/43-card-mirroring) rule to mirror cards across boards when I add a label such as `Shared`, where it creates a two-way link between the cards.

However, I haven't figured out a way to make the changes two way. meaning If a comment is made on the shared board, it also gets reflected on the personal one.