# Is there any way to send a Trello card to an outside user?

Tags: trello-cards

Trello is about perfect for my basic organizational needs, but I can't come up with a solution on how to share card information with an outside user. I'm tracking questions/issues and when done I'd like to be able to send the results (without cutting and pasting) to an outside email. Any solution?

Answer (score 3):

From the Trello help guide:

> Organization admins can make the organizations visibility public or private. You can change the setting in the "Account" page. Private organizations will not show up on your profile when other people view it. They will also not show up in search results.
>
> Organizations also have admins which have the ability to add / remove members, and edit the name and description. To add a member as an admin, click on their avatar in the member list on the profile, and select "Make Admin of Organization".

So it sounds like the only way to do this is to make your board public and share the link right now.

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to share a link to a specific card.

From the [Trello documentation:](http://help.trello.com/article/824-sharing-links-to-cards-and-boards)

> To obtain a link to a card on your board, open the card, click "Share
>   and more..." from the lower right-hand corner of the card back and
>   copy the link to your card.

Comment: we have a private board. we were hoping this would provide access to just this card, but no, it does not. again, it would be helpful if one could give someone read-only access to the card without opening up the rest of the board.

Comment: This does not answer the question which is how, on a private board, you can share a card publicly w/out sharing the board publicly.